# Append @ delimited text file to DBF using c# vfpoledb

Tags: c#, visual-foxpro

Is there any other way of appending @ delimited text file to dbf using c# vfpoledb?

here is a small part of my code but not working:

```
string constr = "Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=" + dir + ";Collating Sequence=general;";
con_oledb.Open();
string query = "EXECSCRIPT( [APPEND FROM " + path + " TYPE DELIMITED WITH CHARACTER @])";
OleDbCommand myQuery = new OleDbCommand(query, con_oledb);
myQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();
con_oledb.Close();
```

dir = path of my dbf file.

path = path of my '@' delimited text file

and the error says that:

An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Feature is not available.

but according to
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa975628(v=vs.71).aspx
all command that i had used is supported.

Comment: Actually, according to that link, the `USE` command is not allowed.

Comment: ow, sorry about that. I'll change my code and remove the 'USE"

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it is not supported that way (use is not supported for example, but you could work that around with a create table if need be).

You could instead use XML to achieve this and then it would be like doing a bulk load. 
Alternatively, you could parse the file with C# and insert into your table via OleDbCommand.

(FWIW I wouldn't rely on anything with execscript, VFP's documentation about *what is supported and what is not* is incorrect).